# Set frame of UIButton but keep image same size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIButton in my app, and it's pretty small. It can be quite hard to tap it sometimes. Is there a way to have a 20px margin around the button, keeping the image the same size? Here's my code:

```
self.helpButton= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.helpButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Info Button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.helpButton addTarget:self
           action:@selector(showHelp)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

if ([[ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 568 ) {
    self.helpButton.frame = CGRectMake(280.0, 528.0, 20, 20);
} else {
    self.helpButton.frame = CGRectMake(280.0, 440.0, 20, 20);
}
```

Basically, I want to have a larger area to tap, but keep the button the same size.

Answer (score 3):

try with setImageEdgeInsets. check this.

```
  if ([[ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 568 ) {
         self.helpButton.frame = CGRectMake(280.0, 528.0, 40, 40);
  } else {
         self.helpButton.frame = CGRectMake(280.0, 440.0, 40, 40);
  }

  [self.helpButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
```

Comment: This changed the size of the button

Answer (score 1):

Subclass UIButton and override `backgroundRectForBounds:` (or `contentRectForBounds:` or whatever works for your use case).

Comment: Is this the only way to do it? It seems quite complicated

Comment: That's a matter of opinion. One man's complicated is another man's easy-peasy. Why not try it?

Answer (score 0):

If your button background colour is clear you can just increase the size of the button. I did this for a delete button with a small image recently:

```
    UIImage *deleteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btnDelete"];

    CGSize btnSize = CGSizeMake(deleteImage.size.width*2, deleteImage.size.height*2);

    self.deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [_deleteButton setImage:deleteImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    _deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,btnSize.width,btnSize.height);
```

Comment: The thing is, my image is quite big, I am scaling it down to 20px x 20px

Comment: I'd suggest adding an image to your project with the correct size and using that then. Alternatively you could create a separate `UIImageView` sized the way you want and add that as a subview of the button instead of setting the button's image.

Comment: Also, wouldn't this put the image in the top right of the frame?

Comment: You can just set the `center` of the imageView to the button's `center`